# enter value when doing Ajax Post with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i'm using "div content editable" html to get value from input keyboard to post with ajax jquery and send to database.
this is my html code

```
<div class="form_field" name="contentbox" id="contentbox" contenteditable="true">
```

and my javascript

```
function mysubmit {
    var contentbox = $("#contentbox").html();
    var contentboxvalue = "contentboxvalue ='" + escape(contentbox) + "'";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/data",
        data: contentboxvalue,
        cache: true,
        success: function () {
            document.getElementById("contentboxInfo").innerHTML = contentbox;
        }
    });

}
```

But I have a problem when I'm updating the value in my database, example: `"hello world"`
and when I'm updating, ajax post jquery send value:

```
"
hello world"
```

How to remove linebreaks (CR/LF), but not `<br>` tags when submitting to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.trim()` to remove extra white-space in a string.

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including
>   non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the
>   supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of
>   the string, they are preserved.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim*

Ex.

```
function mysubmit{
    var contentbox      = $("#contentbox").html(),
        contentboxvalue = "contentboxvalue ='" + escape($.trim(contentbox)) + "'";
    $.ajax({
        type    :"POST",
        url     : "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/data",
        data    : contentboxvalue,
        cache   : true,
        success : function() {
            document.getElementById("contentboxInfo").innerHTML = contentbox;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it at the client side using [jQuery's .trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim). Or on the server side using [PHP's trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

These functions will strip all [white-space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) from the start and end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

i used $.trim() and php trim() and it works for enter value,
next i got problem when i press "enter" in my "div content editable"
when i submit to database, "div content editable" return

> `<p> &nbsp;</p><p> <br/></p>`