# how change pressing enter in div html only return div

Tags: html, keypress, contenteditable

i'm using "div content editable" html i'm using "div content editable" html to get value from input keyboard to post with ajax jquery and send to database. 
in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951615/enter-value-when-doing-ajax-post-with-jquery)

i got problem when i press "enter" in my "div content editable" when i submit to database,

when i press "enter" in my "div content editable", browser return

```
<div>
  <br>
</div>
```

my question, how to change keypress "enter" not become `<br>`, just only `<div> </div>` ???

Comment: `onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) return false;"`

Comment: If you have editable div, I would recommend using one of the WYSIWYG editors available (for example http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php). It is a lot of work and you might find it easier to customize an existing solution rather then building it from scratch.

Comment: @mazzucci i use two type, WYSIWYG ckeditor for my other data, and editable div for my data with tag feature, because WYSIWYG editor can't customize with my tag feature :)

Comment: @hendra I see. I just wanted to make sure you know about the WYSIWYG editors. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @ChasingDeath this code onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) return false; result nothing, can i return "<div></div>" in editable div?

Comment: @hendra instead of `return false` use anything, like `return "<div> </div>";` **Don't forget to use the quotes**

Comment: i try use return "<div> </div>", but didn't work, still result "<div><br></div>"